# How to sort a dictionary from low to high in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sorting

I want to sort the values of this dictionary from low to high:

For example,
input:

```
average = {'ali': 7.83, 'mahdi': 13.4, 'hadi': 16.2, 'hasan': 3.57}
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
{'hasan': 3.57, 'ali': 7.83, 'mahdi': 13.4, 'hadi': 16.2}
```

I tested this method, but because my data is decimal, it gives an error:

```
dict(sorted(average.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Error:

```
ave_dict_sort = dict(sorted(average.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Do `print(average)` before the sort. Are you sure that `average` is what you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sorted function along with a lambda function as the key to achieve this. Here's an example of how you can sort the dictionary by values in ascending order:

```
average = {'ali': 7.83, 'mahdi': 13.4, 'hadi': 16.2, 'hasan': 3.57}

sorted_average = dict(sorted(average.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))

print(sorted_average)
```

This will output:

```
{'hasan': 3.57, 'ali': 7.83, 'mahdi': 13.4, 'hadi': 16.2}
```

Here, sorted(average.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]) sorts the dictionary items based on their values (item[1]), and dict() is used to convert the sorted items back into a dictionary.

Comment: I tried this method before asking but I get this error:
‍‍```
ave_dict_sort = dict(sorted(average.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: The code which I provided you is tested on an online python compiler, please check here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

try to copy paste my code here and see it is working fine, maybe there should be an issue in your compiler.

Comment: @Alimirrezaei It seems that `average` is a float variable - try doing what @slothrop said and run `print(average)` or `print(type(average))`